# How to design a process where an activity is used in different ways?

Tags: bpmn

I have this part of a process:

[image: Process]

I'm trying to describe that `Task 2` may be executed in parallel with `Task 1`, if we are walking the `flow A`, or by itself if we are walking the `flow B`.

It seems to me that the two arrows exiting from `Task 2` are misleading, so I thought that a better version would be this one:

[image: Same process]

where the `Task 2` is duplicated. I don't like duplications, but the latter version seems less ambiguous to me.

Is there a third, correct way? If not, which solutions is correct?

Comment: I think you are right, since your second model is better. Duplication but it is another flow and is easy to understand if anyone ask for flow B.

Comment: What is to the left and rihgt of the diagram? If there are two XOR gateways splitting into flows A and B, just move those into the top-branch and execute Task 1 only ocnditionally.

Comment: @tobias_k this is a semplified model, unfortunately the real one could not be simplified as you suggest.

Comment: @Simone: Notice that your first model implies that after the execution of `Task 2` both flows A and B would be continued, which is not your intended semantics!

Comment: @GerdWagner do you mean that if a token arrives in a task with two outgoing arrows, the token splits and every path is walked?

Comment: Yes, having an activity with two outgoing arrows represents an AND-split (parallel gateway), while incoming arrows represent an OR-join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to express a model that complies with your intended process semantics is defining your `Task 2` as a ***global subprocess activity*** and using a ***call activity*** instead of `Task 2` in your second pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two flows with the help of exclusive gateways. I have added a start event and inclusive gateway at the beginning of the process diagramme below to illustrate the possible scenarios.

1. If it originates in the branch `Flow A`, it will be split at the first and merged in the second parallel gateway as per your original diagramme.
2. If your process instance comes from the branch `Flow B`, it will bypass all parallel gateways and move on to whatever activity follows in flow B (Task 4 in my example).
3. If both flows are activated at the same time, the tokens from flow A will behave as described in 1) and those form flow B as in 2) above.

I personally think a Global Task as proposed by @Gerd Wagner might make your diagramme easier to understand but it would be important to see the rest of your original diagramme to give you a clear-cut judgment.

[image]

Comment: Won't Flow B deadlock after Task 2?

Comment: I thought about that two but the definition of the parallel gateway is a bit ambiguous. It says "For incoming flows, the Parallel Gateway will wait for all incoming flows 
before triggering the flow through its outgoing Sequence Flows." Unfortunately, it does not speak of process instances. In my understanding, a parallel GW waits for all tokens of a given instance. Since flow B only has one token per instance, it would immediately pass that GW upon arrival. For flow A, the GW would wait until both tokens A1 and A2 arrive before sending a newly-merged token A to task 3.

Comment: @khalito: That's a wrong interpretation of the intended execution semantics of BPMN. When they say "wait for all incoming flows", they mean that on each incoming arrow, a "token" needs to arrive. Consequently, your process model would deadlock, indeed, as presumed by tobias_k.

Comment: So, if starting point A would fire 2 process instances (A and AA), which would then turn to 4 tokens after the first parallel gateway (A1, A2, AA1, AA2), then the Task 3 would not carried out until all 4 tokens arrive at the second parallel gateway ? Let's say this is a recruitment process and Task 1 and Task 2 are application review tasks and Task 3 is system task to update the application status. Then, according to this logic, the status of the second application (AA) would not update before the first application (A) is fully reviewed. That also sounds wrong to me.

Comment: This is not about running several process instances in parallel, but simply about the execution of a single process instance, which deadlocks if it comes from your Flow B.

Comment: I see what you mean. I do not have a process engine or modeler at hand that could validate the diagramme and simulate instances but I think you might be right. More importantly, I think I made a mistake assuming that Task 3 would be the next step in flow B, which would effectively merge flow A and B, which does not seem to be the case in the original diagramme (which is why I think a Global Task might indeed be better suited as you have suggested).